# What is an efficient way to isolate dataframe rows with identical values in specific columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```py
AA,    BB,    CC,    _id1,     _id2,     _id3
"foo", "foo", "foo", "1A1A1A", "1A1A1A", "1A1A1A"
"foo", "foo", "foo", "2B2B2B", "4L4L4L", "2B2B2B"
```

I want to isolate rows with `_id` values that are not all identical. In the above example, it would isolate the second row, and ignore the first.

I do not know how many `_id` columns will exist (and need checking) in any given run, and their names will vary (but will be available in as a list of strings: `id_column_names`. The names will also always have `_id` prefix.

Is there any table-wise (or at least series-wise) operation that is reasonably efficient here?

I can of course write some function (to iterate and the relevant row values) and `apply()` it row-wise, but is there a better option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First filter `_id` columns by [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) and then test if same values by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) with first column with [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
df1 = df.filter(regex='^_id')

df = df[~df1.eq(df1.iloc[:, 0], axis=0).all(axis=1)]
print (df)
   AA   BB   CC    _id1    _id2    _id3
1  foo  foo  foo  2B2B2B  4L4L4L  2B2B2B
```

Comment: Thanks. This does work, although it is iterating using `apply()` which was the last part of my question- is there nothing more "pandas-native" or efficient?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, use `df.filter`:

```
df.filter(regex=r'^[_]')
```

To remove these:

```
df.filter(regex=r'^[^_]')
```

Comment: This just isolates the relevant columns. My question relates to filtering the df contents based on row values in specific columns